# The useLoader triggers a re-render of the entire canvas and its in a loop

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

i have 4 files which are selected using file input . they are sent to specs component and I'm using the textureLoader and useLoader hook of react-three-fiber to render the component to the scene. when i comment out the map property of the meshmaterial it will render 4 planes , but when i try to add texture it'll cause continuous re-render. how can it be solved. below is the code.

```
import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import React from "react";
import { DoubleSide, TextureLoader } from "three";

/**
 * specs value is in the order frame , stickL ,stickR
 * ,glass because it is being filtered in the handle input section
 *
 */
const specsValues = [
  { position: [0, -0.1, 0] },
  { position: [0.5, -0.1, -0.5], rotation: 0.5 * Math.PI },
  { position: [-0.5, -0.1, -0.5], rotation: -0.5 * Math.PI },
  { position: [0, -0.1, 0] },
];
//converst number into radian 
const Specs = ({ files }) => {
  console.log(files);
  function degToRad(x) {
    return x * (Math.PI / 180);
  }

  return (
    <mesh
      scale={[14, 6.75, 16.5]}
      position={[0, 22.5, 14]}
      rotation-x={degToRad(6)}
    >
      {files.map((e, index) => {
        return <Part image={e} key={index} index={index} />;
      })}
    </mesh>
  );
};

/**
 * specs value is in the order frame , stickL ,stickR
 * ,glass because it is being filtered in the handle input section
 *
 */

const Part = ({ image, index }) => {
  const imageUrl = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (typeof image === "string") {
      return image;
    } else {
      return URL.createObjectURL(image);
    }
  }, [image]);

  const texture = useLoader(TextureLoader, imageUrl); // Load texture only once

  // Clean up URL when component unmounts
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (typeof image !== "string") {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(imageUrl);
      }
    };
  }, [image, imageUrl]);

  console.log(imageUrl);
  return (
    <mesh
      rotation-y={specsValues[index].rotation}
      position={specsValues[index].position}
    >
      <meshBasicMaterial
        color={"#fff"}
        side={DoubleSide}
        map={texture}
        // transparent={true}
        // map={useLoader(TextureLoader, imageUrl)}
      />
      <planeGeometry args={[1, 1]} />
    </mesh>
  );
};

export default Specs;
```

i tried to memoize the loading texture functionality  and passed the image file as the dependency expecting it not to re-render , but it did not work.

the problem may be related to the image url being different each time it is created. as the useLoader caches the urls each time the url is created its passes a new url to the useLoader it will trigger rerender.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by performing the url generation outside the canvas and passing it as props to the canvas.but if there are any other solution please feel free to add them.